# Java Log4j2 Syslog Appender doen't send messages

Tags: java, log4j2, syslog

I'm trying to use Log4j2 Syslog Appender but no messages are sent.
I'm monitoring the environment using WireShark and no messages are detected.
Running on Windows 7.

When I use Kiwi syslog, the messages arrive just fine.

Here is my log4j2 XML configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
           <Syslog name="RFC5424" format="RFC5424" host="localhost" port="514"
            protocol="UDP" appName="MyApp" includeMDC="true"
            facility="USER" enterpriseNumber="18060" newLine="true"
            messageId="Audit" mdcId="mdc" id="App"
            connectTimeoutMillis="1000" reconnectionDelayMillis="5000">
            <LoggerFields>
                <KeyValuePair key="thread" value="%t"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="priority" value="%p"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="category" value="%c"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="exception" value="%ex"/>
                <KeyValuePair key="message" value="%m"/>
            </LoggerFields>
        </Syslog>
      </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Logger name="com.mycorp" level="info" />
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="RFC5424"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Here is my Java code:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class SyslogLogger
{
    private static final Logger LOG = LogManager.getLogger(SyslogLogger.class);

    public static void main (String[] args)throws IOException,SQLException
    {
        LOG.error("testing ERROR level");
    }
}
```

The console appender works fine, but the syslog doesn't.

Please advise.

Comment: Check the err-output. I guess your log4j.xml is broken and thus the default config is used. Appenders are configured using the "appender" tag with attributes.

Comment: @Fildor, I'm looking in my console output, no errors.

Comment: @Fildor, I've updated the question, please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try code below and check it:

```
<appender name="Console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
     <param name="Target" value="System.out"/>
     <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
     </layout>
</appender>
```

Comment: Any changes need to be made in reference to the Syslog Appender?

Comment: SysLog appender has to be changed accordingly.

Comment: Searching for it, I found an example looking like yours: It was a log4j**2** config example. If you are using log4j 1.2 , config has to look like Jigar says.

Comment: @Fildor, I'm using the example XML in this link, does not work.
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#SyslogAppender